# Having the Current Search Results Tab Stay Selected When Query Changes

Tags: html, google-programmable-search-engine

In Google custom search, there are two tabs. Images and Web (Search Results). When you are in the images tab, and you change or reenter your search query, the tab changes back to the Web tab. What could I do to prevent this? I do not want to set the images tab to the default tab, but I just want the user to be able to control whether they are searching for images or search results just by clicking either tab. You can see for yourself what I'm talking about here:
https://codepen.io/FreezingChima/pen/BaPVaBy

Comment: I think that you have to live with what Google has provided.